# Application pool is stopped when the site is on high traffic

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5, asp.net, application-pools

Sorry if I am asking a silly question here.

We are having problem with one of our websites. Its application pool is stopped whenever the site has high traffic as we notice it always happens when the company send out EDM and the number of concurrent visitors went up.

Other websites using the same .NET version are working fine without any problem. We are using the following technologies.

```
ASP.NET 2.0 (Web site project)
IIS 7.5
Windows Web Server 2008 R2
```

I found the following error in event viewer.

[image]

What could be causing the problem? Could that be because of dead-locks in our website? If so, how can we find it out? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is usually an ASP.NET code issue.  From what I'm finding online, that specific code (0x80070057) refers to an invalid parameter.

You might want to set up a crash rule with [the Debug Diagnostics tool](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919789).  That's probably your best bet for finding what's causing the crashes.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Katherine. I have downloaded the tool and attached to App Pool process. Let's wait and see what report it can generate.